# работа с процессами в windows C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

В Ubuntu есть парка /proc в которой содержится много информации о процессах на компьютере, я использую её для обработки информации. Вопрос,как обрабатывать процессы в windows есть что то похожее. Условно мне надо узнать если процесс с таким именем, если да собирать инфу о нем. Пишу на си/c++.

Comment: В Windows имеется полноценное API. см https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses

Comment: Может boost process

Answer (score 0):

В Windows для этого есть API:

[Process and Thread Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/procthread/process-and-thread-functions)

[PSAPI Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/psapi/psapi-functions)

[Tool Help Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-functions)

Также есть [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/about-wmi). [`Win32 Provider`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-provider) предоставляет множество классов для получения системной информации, включая класс [`Win32_Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process).